# generalized implicitly restarted lanczos method

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, generalized-eigenvector

I am looking for references on how to solve the generalized eigen-problem :
$$Ax = \lambda Bx \tag{1}$$
Where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is symmetric positive definite.
I know a standard approach is to perform a Cholesky factorisation of $B$ and then to solve :
$$L^{-1}AL^{-T}y = \lambda y \tag{2}$$
With $B = LL^T$, $y = L^T x$.
And then to apply an implicitly restarted Lanczos (or Arnoldi) method.

I would like to know if it is possible to use an implicitly restarted (Generalized) Lancozs method directly to (1).